# proper grammar of multiple numbers ordered sequentially specifying different things

Tags: hyphenation, numbers

I have a sentence submitted to me from someone else that says

```
One case (8 - one lb. boxes) of...
```

What is the proper grammar to say eight one pound boxes?  I'm not sure what the best format is for this situation.  Maybe one of these is acceptable:

```
eight 1-lb. boxes
eight one lb. boxes
8 one pound boxes
8 one-pound boxes
eight one-pound boxes
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is more a matter of style than of grammar, but any style accepting _eighty one pound boxes_ is one I'd avoid. It needs a hyphen to disambiguate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with either of your last two examples. The hyphen links 'one-pound' as a unit, which is also a single adjective. You want eight boxes, and each of them is a one-pound box.

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to avoid confusion, just make a clear separation between the item name and the item quantity.

```
Item 1:  One pound boxes.  Quantity: 8 items. 
Item 2:  Elephants. Quantity: 2.
```

...and so on.

In normal conversation or writing most of your alternatives are clear enough to be considered correct.

Answer (score 0):

In technical/logistical specifications where clarity is important:

```
8 x 1 lb boxes.
```

In normal writing

```
Eight one pound boxes.
```

Logistical specification requiring clarity but conforming to normal English structure

```
One unit of one pound box of strawberries.  
Eight units of one pound box of strawberries.  
Eight items of two pound box of jalapenos.  
Eight boxes of five pounds each of oranges.
```